# PhpStorm Unknown keyCode: 0x0

Tags: java, phpstorm, key-bindings

When I trying to use default keymaps like Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V, etc. they not working.

When I trying to map custom keymap, I get error by pressing on character keys:

```
Unknown keyCode: 0x0
```

What it can be? I tried to install Java 1.6, 1.7, same thing.

PS: Using Fedora 19

**EDIT**

My default lang is English. But playing with keyboard settings of XFCE made it work oO. Issue with keyboard layouts.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What's your **primary** keyboard layout. Make sure it's English and not Russian.
2. Try adding `-Dide.non.english.keyboard.layout.fix=true` into your `idea.properties` file.

Actual ticket for further reference: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80613

Comment: Changing the primary keyboard layout is exactly what helped me on Lubuntu 22.04 and phpStorm 2022.3. For those that wonder - this is the system setting you can find in Start menu>Preferences>LXQt settings>Keyboard and Mouse>Keyboard layout. Just move the English layout at the top, and then restart phpStorm.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the main keyboard layout from XFCE settings to **English(Macintosh)** worked for me! (*after long struggle*)

You might need to play with the keyboard layout variant to match your physical keyboard

Tested with Oracle Java 1.7 on Debian 64bit (Jessie)

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround:

Copy from here https://github.com/zheludkovm/LinuxJavaFixes two files:

```
LinuxJavaFixes-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
```

Add the following line to JVM options:
`-javaagent:[path to directory with jar files]/LinuxJavaFixes-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

For example, you can add this lines to ~/.profile

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS="-javaagent:[path to directory with jar files]/LinuxJavaFixes-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
export _JAVA_OPTIONS
```

Thanks [zheludkovm](https://github.com/zheludkovm) and [Sergey Komarov](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80613#comment=27-773762)