# Webstorm 11.0.2 ctrl+key is not working

Tags: webstorm, copy-paste, ctrl

I just installed WebStorm 11.0.2 on my Mac with Visual Studio keymap settings scheme. But afterwords I realized that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> etc is not working.

[image]

I've looked into this similar [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568662/ctrl-v-and-ctrl-c-doesnt-work-in-intellij-idea-14-0-2) but I do not have the vim plugin installed.

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135661/phpstorm-unknown-keycode-0x0